# Need to help in adding bigendian support for Keccak256.cpp

Tags: solidity, cpp-ethereum, keccak, hash-algorithm

Need help in making the keccakf function based on endiness in `https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/libdevcore/Keccak256.cpp`. I have gone through similar functionality at `https://github.com/stbrumme/hash-library/blob/master/keccak.cpp`. but unable to re write keccakf function in Keccak256.cpp. Any help on this would be very helpfull

Comment: I think you need to modify the xorin which executes dst[i] ^= src[i] to something like dst[i] ^= swap(src[i])

Comment: @Ismael thanks for the input.but It didn't work.